# flutter : can not read properties of null (reading color)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, null, widget

i am running this code and i get error of
can not read properties of null (reading color)

in line that starred in code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:untitled/constants.dart';
import 'package:untitled/models/product.dart';
import 'package:untitled/screens/home/components/categories.dart';

class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  const Body({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: Text(
            "Women",
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .headline5
                .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
        Categories(),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
            child: GridView.builder(
              itemCount: products.length,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                childAspectRatio: 0.75,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (Context, index) => ItemCard(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ItemCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Product product;
  final Function press;
  const ItemCard({
    Key key,
    this.product,
    this.press,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: press,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
*               color: product.color,   //error in that line
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              ),
              child: Hero(
                tag: "${product.id}",
                child: Image.asset(product.image),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
            child: Text(
              product.title,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: ktextlightcolor,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            "\$${product.price}",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

this is product.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Product {
  final String image, title, description;
  final int price, size, id;
  var color;
  Product({
    this.id,
    this.image,
    this.title,
    this.price,
    this.description,
    this.size,
    this.color,
  });
}

List<Product> products = [
  Product(
    id: 1,
    title: "office code",
    price: 232,
    size: 12,
    description: dummyText,
    image: "assets/images/bag_1.png",
    color: const Color(0XFF3D82AE),
  ),
  Product(
      id: 2,
      title: "belt bag",
      price: 234,
      size: 8,
      description: dummyText,
      image: "assets/images/bag_2.png",
      color: const Color(0xffd3a084)),
  Product(
      id: 3,
      title: "hang top",
      price: 444,
      size: 13,
      description: dummyText.
      image: "assets/images/bag_3.png",
      color: const Color(0XFF989493)),
  Product(
      id: 4,
      title: "old fashion",
      price: 555,
      size: 18,
      description: dummyText,
      image: "assets/images/bag_4.png",
      color: const Color(0xffe6b398)),
  Product(
      id: 5,
      title: "office code",
      price: 999,
      size: 33,
      description: dummyText,
      image: "assets/images/bag_5.png",
      color: const Color(0xfffb7883)),
  Product(
      id: 6,
      title: "siple bag",
      price: 1299,
      size: 6,
      description: dummyText,
      image: "assets/images/bag_6.png",
      color: const Color(0xffaeaeae)),
];

String dummyText =
    "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a product instance to your `ItemCard` constructor. It is currently set as an optional parameter as it is wrapped with `{}`.

So, assuming that you would like to pass the products from your `products` list, it should be something like this:

```
Expanded(
  child: Padding(
    ...,
    child: GridView.builder(
      itemCount: products.length,
      ...,
      itemBuilder: (Context, index) => ItemCard(product: products[index]),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass parameter on ItemCard() class, where you already mention 2 arguments. You did not pass any param. Update your code like below :

```
itemBuilder: (Context, index) => ItemCard(product: products[index], press: press)
```